# Writing a better loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm creating a script that will search the database and look for customers that are in the Realtors latitude and longitude boundary range. If the customer lat and long coordinates is within the range of the realtor's lat and long boundaries then this script will email **only the Realtor in that customers range**.  I'm using a CRON job to run the php script.  I got the script to email each person that is in range of the Realtors but when a third Realtor is entered into the database **the email goes to the third Realtor even though the lat and long is out of range**.

How do I write a **better** loop where each row gets checked if the client is in range of that Realtor and only email that Realtor **only**?  Thanks.

Here is my SQL code.

```
CREATE TABLE `realtors` (
    `rid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `rEmail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `rZipCode` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `rDist` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `rlatitude` numeric(30,15) NOT NULL,
    `rlongitude` numeric(30,15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `customers` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `eMail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `zipCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `clatitude` numeric(30,15) NOT NULL,
    `clongitude` numeric(30,15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is my php code.

```
<?php
use geocodeloc\GeoLocation as GeoLocation;
require_once 'geocodeloc/GeoLocation.php';
//require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$db = getDB();
//database prep for customers
$cust = $db->prepare("SELECT fullName, eMail, clatitude, clongitude FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC");
$cust->bindParam("fullName", $fullName,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cust->bindParam("zipCode", $zipCode,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cust->bindParam("eMail", $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cust->bindParam("clatitude", $clatitude,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cust->bindParam("clongitude", $clongitude,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cust->execute();
$cust->rowCount();

//database prep for realtors
$realt = $db->prepare("SELECT rEmail, rDist, rlatitude, rlongitude FROM realtors ORDER BY rid DESC");
$realt->bindParam("rZipCode", $rZipCode,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$realt->bindParam("rEmail", $rEmail,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$realt->bindParam("rDist", $rDist,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$realt->bindParam("rlatitude", $rlatitude,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$realt->bindParam("rlongitude", $rlongitude,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$realt->execute();
$realt->rowCount();

$i = -1;

while ($realtor_row = $realt ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) AND $customers_row = $cust ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $i++;
        $realtLatLong = GeoLocation::fromDegrees( $realtor_row['rlatitude'], $realtor_row['rlongitude']);
        $coordinates = $realtLatLong->boundingCoordinates($realtor_row['rDist'], 'miles');

              //look to see if customers latitude and longitude is within range of the realtors lat and long boundaries.
          if($customers_row['clatitude'] && $customers_row['clongitude'] <= $coordinates){
           //email the realtor

          // the message
          $msgBody = "This is a test";

          // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
          $msgBody = wordwrap($msgBody,70);

          $Mailto = $realtor_row['rEmail'];
          $FromName = $customers_row['fullName'];

          // send email
          mail($Mailto, $FromName , $msgBody);

        }else{
         //send to debug log
        }

};
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping through the entire result set and doing the calculations is going to kill your database very quickly. Looping through one table and then looping through another to do a distance comparison is going to kill your database even faster. Luckily this is a re invention of the wheel. Mysql has built in functionality for this by way of ST_Distance

```
SELECT * FROM realtors INNER JOIN customers WHERE ST_within(customers.loc, realtors.loc) < 10; /* location in degrees */
```

Where one degree is approximately 111 kilometer. You whould need to change your table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `realtors` (
    `rid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `rEmail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `rZipCode` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `rDist` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `loc` point NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`rid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `customers` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `eMail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `zipCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `loc` POINT not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

of course this requires mysql  5.7

Using a spatial data type means that you can use an index for spatial looksup. In an RDBS if a table contains N rows, having an indes means you do not need to check through all those N number of rows to find a result. Thus using spatial data here + an index you can avoid the NxM time complexity you might have with lat,lng in separate columns.

Comment: @ e4c5 Ok I'm lost now so I updated my sql as above and updated my code.  The other way I had it was kind of working but now this one is not working at all.  Now I'm getting this Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' error.

Comment: post the full error. The exact prepared statement you tried to use and the erxact error you got

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /home/keithte2/public_html/emailer.php:50 Stack trace: #0 /home/keithte2/public_html/emailer.php(50): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/keithte2/public_html/emailer.php on line 50

Comment: $db = getDB();
//database prep for customers
$realtCust = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM realtors INNER JOIN customers WHERE ST_within(customers.loc, realtors.loc) < 10; ?* location in degrees */");
$realtCust->bindParam("loc", $loc,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$realtCust->execute();
$realtCust->rowCount();

Comment: oops sorry  messed up my comment which was supposed to nbe `/* location in degrees */`

Comment: I'm thinking of editing and reposting this question because I'm working on a big project and the only part I'm having trouble with is the email part.  I kind of get what your saying about killing the database but this day and age I thought that databases can handle looping through results multiple times.

Comment: A  properly designed RDBMS on a very low end server can outperform a poorly designed system on a 16 core machine with 64 GB ram. Sad to say it looks like this is what you have (the latter)

Comment: @e4c5 Very much impressed by your previous comment I would love to see your tuts or guides. are there any..?  I'm mid-lev developer and suck at sql and design. I see soothing light in your username ^_^

Comment: thank you @Bsienn sadly my blog is now almost defunct. Glad that you have found my answers usefull

Comment: This is just a test server.  Also for the comment I found this site to be helpful.  (http://coding-geek.com/how-databases-work/) Thanks for the help.

Comment: obviously one would think that what you are testing locally is what you would eventually deploy.

Comment: Ok so if I'm joining two tables should I name the other column 'locb'?

Comment: you can name the columns anything you like. Now the moderators are going to jump on us for having such long discussions in chat. Please post a new question if you have any new problems

Answer (score 0):

No matter how fast you can make your code, the complexity will still be NxM.

First thing you should do is to create a relationship between Customer and Realtor, i.e. a table with Customer.id and Realtor.id. Take a hit the first time you populate this table (no need to change your code). After that, you just need to create a relationship everytime a Customer or a Realtor got added.

When it's time to send your email, you just need to look at the relationship table.